# How to secure web pages with token based authentication?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm building a website using ruby on rails which is hosted separately which makes requests to another backend api rails app which is again hosted separately. Obviously i've setup the backend api with token based oauth authentication.

Now since im not dealing with sessions, and it being stateless n all, How can I stop users from accessing certain view pages in my front end web app? For example, I have a consumer/booking page. I don't want the user to access this page without being logged in. But anyone can just enter the url and open any page they want right now.

On user login (ajax call from .js.erb files), im getting the token and storing it in localStorage variable for every future request to the api. I know I should use this token somehow to stop users from access restricted pages. But I just dont know how.

Comment: I haven't tried, however I think you check this [GoRails video](https://gorails.com/episodes/api-auth-with-json-web-tokens-and-knock) on API auth on JWT.

Comment: im using doorkeeper gem for oauth

Answer (score 1):

Now as you have stored the `token` in the `localStorage`, **you will need to pass this token with the request to the page where you want to restrict access** and check if the user is authorized to access the page or not.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: there is no standard method or library for this; you must implement such functionality as you see fit.

I'm assuming you're using some sort of front end framework like react; if so, then any request to change the current view should be terminated if there is no valid token in localStorage. Check out [this post](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) regarding conditional rendering in React; if you're using something else, the methodology is still pretty much the same.

Otherwise, I would build a small script to include in the beginning of every page that checks whether or not there is a valid token and if there isn't, calls `window.history.back()` to return the user to the previous page.

(Another way of doing it is to intercept every call to a static HTML file on the server, check if there's a token, and send the file if there is. Otherwise, you can send a custom error page or whatever).